# Facebook Connection error on Device in iPhone

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api, device

I am building an app in which I need Facebook connection for that m using Graph API. I am using extended permission like `friends_birthday` using following code.

```
NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"friends_birthday", nil];
[facebook authorize:permissions];
```

Everything is fine when running on simulator ,but while running on device it shows connection error, `Err code: 10000`.
Please suggest me if I am missing any thing. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Update facebook app or try to remove and reinstall the facebook app